# SVG Scale Animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I am trying to modify this SVG code below to change the Scale Animation from Center Point instead of Upper-Left Corner.

The transform I want to scale from 1 to 0.8 (smaller)

```
[https://codepen.io/Binh-Pham-the-bold/pen/dyaLqdG][1]
```

```html
<svg id="spinnerLoaderRef"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     width="150"
     height="150"
     overflow="visible"
     fill="#20207A"
     stroke="none"
     class="single-loader">
    <defs>

        <circle id="spinner"
                r="8"
                cx="50"
                cy="50"
                transform="translate(0 -30)" />
    </defs>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xlink:href="#spinner">
        <animate attributeName="opacity"
                 values="0;1;0"
                 dur="1s"
                 begin="0s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="scale"
                          additive="sum"
                          dur="1s"
                          begin="0.13s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"
                          from="1"
                          to="0.8"></animateTransform>
    </use>
</svg>
```

Please help to change it,
thanks

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transform-origin and transform-box.

```html
<svg id="spinnerLoaderRef"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     width="150"
     height="150"
     overflow="visible"
     fill="#20207A"
     stroke="none"
     class="single-loader">
    <defs>

        <circle id="spinner"
                r="8"
                cx="50"
                cy="50"
                transform="translate(0 -30)" />
    </defs>
    <style>
    use {
    transform-origin:center;
    transform-box:fill-box;
    }
    </style>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xlink:href="#spinner">
        <animate attributeName="opacity"
                 values="0;1;0"
                 dur="1s"
                 begin="0s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="scale"
                          additive="sum"
                          dur="1s"
                          begin="0.13s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"
                          from="1"
                          to="0.8"></animateTransform>
    </use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
style="scale: 0.8; transform-origin: 0 0;"
```

[image]

Comment: I mean the center scale of the circle, it's not svg position

Comment: then add style="scale: 0.8; transform-origin: 0 0;" to your SVG. and change the transform-origin to get your desired position

Comment: what's the element you want to add style: circle tag, SVG tag ...?

Comment: As I mentioned, add it to the SVG tag

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: Posted a picture